# Tricky .htaccess and Drupal problem

Tags: php, drupal, .htaccess

**1)** <strike>I have a Drupal site located at `http://example.com` and I have a directory located at `http://example.com/foo`, but I also have a Drupal page with an alias of `http://example.com/foo`. How can I get the Drupal page to serve? Currently, I get a 403 forbidden page as a result of the `Options -Indexes` declaration in Drupal's .htaccess file, but I do not want to remove this as I do not want directories to be browsable.</strike>

**EDIT:** I have solved this with the following rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://localhost/s2k/index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

**2)** To make the problem even more difficult, given the same scenario, if I have an `index.html` file inside the directory `http://example.com/foo/index.html` I always want this to take priority over Drupal's aliased page (which it does at the moment - currently I have modified the .htaccess file so that any directory with an index.html file displays it - `DirectoryIndex index.php index.html`).

**EDIT:**

So now, how can I write a RewriteCond that will look to see whether or not there is an index.html file inside the directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.html !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://localhost/s2k/index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: What a legend. A king amongst men.

Comment: Where did the s2k directory come from?

Answer (score 3):

I am no RewriteRule Guru and pretty sure there is a nicer way to achieve this, e.g. with conditional RewriteCond.

But simply adding

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} =/foo/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Above the default rewrite Conds and rules make this rule kick in for /foo/ and not the Drupal-default one. Where a `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` will only apply the RewriteRule if something is NOT a dir.

Comment: You inspired a solution to part of the problem - thanks. Any ideas for part 2?

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}index.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1index.html [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1/index.html [L]

[normal Drupal rewrite rules]
```